# Como evitar que se impriman datos basura?

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

> Hacer un algoritmo que permita ingresar números por pantalla y luego informar la cantidad de pares,
> el promedio de los divisibles por 5 ingresados.
> Finaliza cuando ingresan un 0 (cero). (El cero no debe considerarse PAR)

Y lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int num,cont=0,cont1=0,prome,acum;
    do{
    printf("Ingresa numeros:\n");
    scanf("%i", &num);
    if(num==0)
    {
        printf("no es par");
    }
    if( num % 2 ==0)
        {
            cont++;
        } 
     if (num % 5 == 0)
     {
        cont1++;
        acum= acum + num;
        prome= acum / cont1;
     }
      }while (num!=0); 
      printf("\n\n El total de numeros pares es: %i \n\n", cont-1);
      printf("\n El promedio de los divisibles por 5 es %i\n", prome);  
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

El problema es que en la función ***printf*** de la linea 26 que muestra el promedio, este arroja datos basura y no se como resolverlo

Comment: Por la división `prome` es double o float y estás imprimiendo un entero `%i`, intenta con `%f`

Comment: Acabo de cambiarlo y me da siempre resultado 0

Comment: 3 veces el 5, y me da un resultado basura igual que antes

Comment: Sigue igual, siempre arroja datos basura

Comment: No, no utilizo malloc

Comment: No logro hacer que funcione, tampoco se usar la función malloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`acum` no está inicializado.

Cuando el valor ingresado es cero, tienes que evitar probar las condiciones de divisible por 2 y 5, pues en ambos casos `num % 2` y `num % 5` te dara cero. Por consecuencia, también tienes cambiar la instrucción imprimir el contador de números pares (no tienes que restarle uno).

El código corregido es:

```
int main() {
    int num, cont = 0, cont1 = 0, prome, acum = 0;
    do {
        printf("Ingresa numeros:\n");
        scanf("%i", &num);
        if (num == 0) {
            printf("no es par");
        } else {
            if (num % 2 == 0) {
                cont++;
            }
            if (num % 5 == 0) {
                cont1++;
                acum = acum + num;
                prome = acum / cont1;
            }
        }
    } while (num != 0);
    printf("\n\n El total de numeros pares es: %i \n\n", cont);
    printf("\n El promedio de los divisibles por 5 es %i\n", prome);
```

**Demo**

```
Ingresa numeros:
2
Ingresa numeros:
2
Ingresa numeros:
5
Ingresa numeros:
5
Ingresa numeros:
10
Ingresa numeros:
0
no es par

 El total de numeros pares es: 3 


 El promedio de los divisibles por 5 es 6
```

Comment: Perfecto! Ahora puedo ver que mi código estaba bastante mal y entendí el porque, muchas gracias!